# iOS Autolayout issue when change in height constraint

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, autolayout, constraints

I have to create expandable view (not taking table view). and on the button click it should be expand/collapse . i Set height constraint and on the clicking of button , i expand/collapse with the below code

```
@IBAction func btnLastDayCostExpandClicked(_ sender: Any) {

        if isLastdayCostOpened {
            isLastdayCostOpened = false
           // lastDayCostHeightConstraint.constant = 34
            lastDayHeightConstraint.constant = 34

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }

        } else {
            isLastdayCostOpened = true
           lastDayHeightConstraint.constant = 90
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            } 
        } 
    }
```

When its screen load first time

[image]

it is not correct as white view goes up side (height 30) and after clicking on button  its expand

[image]

and looks good

any help!

Comment: Set clipToBounds property of your view to TRUE.

Comment: What is the `constant` on the constraint on the first load?

Comment: @Fogmeister its 30 for the first time . when it will expand it set as 90

Comment: @DSDharma let me check at run time .

Comment: @DSDharma Thanks a lot its done

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, please share more information about your view hierarchy and what you are trying to achieve, as I am a bit confused.

From what I gather you want when collapsing the view to hide the containing elements. If that is the case, make sure your UIView with the white BG is the parent view of the elements you want too show/hide and try the following:

You need to set clipToBounds to true for the UIView containing those elements (White Background).

That way, when it collapses it will hide the containing elements.

Hope that helps.